# IF and RIGHT formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am attempting to extract two digits from the right side of a string.

The input string can end with digits or text. For example:
`Hitch Rack - 4-Bike` and `Mountain-100 Silver, 38`.

My end goal is to pull the last two digits if they exist into another cell.  If the initial string doesn't end with the digits, I want to output a `" "`.

Currently, my brain is telling me this, where `[@Product]` is the input cell string value:

```vba
=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT([@Product],2)),RIGHT([@Product],2)," ")
```

Using the two input examples above I should get: `" "` (space) and `38` as the outputs respectively.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You seem to be on the right track, but I don't really understand what your question is?

Comment: And your formula does not work?

Comment: `=IFERROR(1*(RIGHT([@Product],2)),"")`

Answer (score 1):

Try typing *1 after the right() formula:

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(RIGHT([@Product],2)*1)),RIGHT([@Product],2)*1," ")

If you use left/right/mid in excel, it returns the output as a string (e.g. "38") which is text, not a number. Multiplying by 1 makes it a number, if the return values are letters you get an error.

Comment: Yes!  Works now.  Thank you :)

Comment: Nice! The iferror formula commented by Tim Williams should work as well and is even shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

One more method pasted below -

=IFERROR(IF(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(H8,2)),RIGHT(H8,2)," ")," ")